# Word Add-in: Disable "Save as" based on document's path

Tags: c#, ms-word, ribbon, office-addins

I need to write a Word Add-in (supporting 2013+) to conditionally disable the "Save as" option/tab, based on the path of the currently opened document (e. g. where it is stored).

I'm using C# and have the following xml, which disables the tab, but sadly does this for **every** document:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <backstage>
    <button idMso="FileSaveAs" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabSave" visible="false"/>
  </backstage>
</customUI>
```

I've tried:

- DocumentBeforeSave-Handler: Lets me show an error dialog, but doesn't hide the "Save as"
- using getVisible instead of visible in the xml to reference callbacks: The callbacks were never called, not even after invalidating the ribbon via ribbon.Invalidate()

Would be really grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: Which add-in technology are you using? Using a getVisible or getEnabled callback is going to be your only option. Show us the relevant code in your solution for handling the ribbon, with the callback. Also note: some commands in the File menu can't be removed, but can be disabled. Try getEnabled, as well, and see if that works.

Comment: Note that anything you do in your add-in will apply to all documents. Only Ribbon customizations saved *in* a document will apply to that document. A Ribbon customization can be added to a document via its Open XML file format, using the Open XML SDK, for example.

Comment: @CindyMeister: I don't think "getVisible" / "getEnabled" callbacks are supported for the built-in commands (like "Save As").

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Cindy and Nikolay! If I cannot change the ribbon on a per document basis without adding the customization to each document, then this question is answered.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't - I just saying saving a Ribbon customization in the document is the only way to associate/link something directly to the document. It should be possible to do it dynamically using code, in some form or another. But you do need to provide the additional information I requested so that we have a valid starting point.

Comment: I can't show the code, but I have a ThisAddIn.cs which has a method "CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject", which just returns an instance of a class loading the xml to disable the buttons (via GetCustomUI method).

Answer (score 0):

The following approach works in Word 2013, Word 2016 and Word 2019 (call backs to hide/disable built-in Tabs are disallowed but not Commands).

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" xmlns:x="MyComAddin.Connect" onLoad="RibbonOnLoad">
    <commands>
        <command idMso="TabSave" getEnabled="GetEnabledCallback" />
    </commands>
    <backstage onShow="BackstageOnShowCallback">
    </backstage>
</customUI>
```

Then simply call Ribbon.Invalidate() from the BackstageOnShowCallback and the DocumentChange events (DocumentChange event as well otherwise toggling between documents you want to control and documents you don't want to control will give inconsistent results).

It only needs Ribbon.InvalidateControlMso("TabSave") - but if you want to do the same for buttons FileSave, FileSaveAs etc then the global Ribbon.Invalidate() is simpler.

Slightly surprising that Command call backs work on built-in Tabs etc when the same thing in backstage does not.

Comment: I deleted the answer because it's a naa: starts by a question and ends with "Be interested in your thoughts". If you edit to make it look more like an answer I may consider undeleting

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but thought this might help..

The ribbon xml is just a string and as such can be manipulated.

Ribbon XML:

```
<backstage>
  <tab idMso="TabSave" visible="%IsSaveTabVisible%"/>
</backstage>
```

Code:

```
public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
{
    try
    {
        string ribbonXml = GetResourceText("Ribbon.xml");
        if (...)
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml.Replace("%IsSaveTabVisible%", "true");
        else
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml.Replace("%IsSaveTabVisible%", "false");
        return ribbonXml;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Message.ShowError(ex);
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

-- Edit --

Reread your post and realised that you want the visibility to change each time the document changes. I don't think this approach will work as i think it can only be applied as Word starts.